# MYSQLi layout vs MYSQL fetch array old school

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, echo

Is there a way to make the old layout of my website with MYSQL to work with the new MYSQLi ? But I dont mean with php echo " crap style html" I mean the follow old school html made easy for better view and custom easy design:

here is the code example:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'gggggg', 'gggggg') ;
mysql_select_db ('ggggg');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username =".$_POST['profile'];
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$username = stripslashes($row['username']);
$age = stripslashes($row['age']);
$gender = stripslashes($row['gender']);
?>



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
CUSTOM HTML FOR A NICE DESIGN WITHOUT PRINTS OR CRAP JUST NICE AND EASY just like old school

    CATEGORY <?php echo $username; ?>
    TITEL <?php echo $age; ?>
    CONTENT <?php echo $sex; ?>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What are you even asking here? "crap style html". "oldschool html made easy for better view and custom easy design" - this is fluff verbiage that has no relevance to the issue at hand what so ever. Furthermore, if those values weren't set in the DB and the MySQl call didn't retrieve those, it would throw `undefined index` errors.

Comment: sorry better I explain. Asked the same in other place and I got some answers there I must Array or something between ECHO "html here" and that is a pain in the a** to work like that about design you know ... Thats why I preffer this way old school because of the design thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some minor differences between `mysql` and `mysqli` used as a procedural extension, but you should be able to do almost exactly what you do now.

For example:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'gggggg', 'gggggg') ; // $Connection needed for later calls
mysqli_select_db ($conn, 'ggggg');                         // incloude the connection variable for each call

$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username =".$_POST['profile'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);             // Connection variable required

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

$username = stripslashes($row['username']);
$age = stripslashes($row['age']);
$gender = stripslashes($row['gender']);
```

You will need to take the usual precautions against SQL injection. You may wish to consider using prepared statements for that. You'll also need to add any requisite error checking.

Comment: as I dont know so much about prepared staments but reading I see the change in my example would be: POST profile to be changed to S execute and so on but how about the WHILE ROW MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY will it work just like that ? Thanks

Comment: Nice answer, but you've left him wide open for SQL injection. Why not show an example using prepared statements to facilitate best practices?

Comment: I would love to see the same example in prepared staments to learn that and so create my site using based on this simple example. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm trying to stay on topic. OP has posted a simple example to illustrate what he needs to know. I have followed that to demonstrate that a transition to `mysqli` needn't be painful. I have highlighted areas where more work would be required - the OP can explore that himself or ask further questions if appropriate

Comment: choosed your question. Started a new one if you wanna help me